# Determine if a great circle is on the left or right from a point defined by latitude, longitude and bearing

Tags: geometry, latitude-longitude, geolocation, mathematics, navigation

### Given

1. A point coordinate on the map specified by latitude and longitude. Shown as "C" on pictures below.
2. Direction where this point is moving, specified by bearing in degrees (0-359), where 0° means the point is moving strictly to North, 90° - to East, etc.
3. Two points (A, B) specified by latitude and longitude. These points define a line that point C should move towards.

[image]

### Question

How can I determine whether the line is on the left or right side from the point C?

### Examples

[image]

### What may help

I think this problem can be solved using cross product calculation like in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1560492/2613692), but I'm not sure how I would apply it having the coordinates defined by latitude and longitude.

I need to solve this problem using Swift programming language, but a solution using any other language or formulas would suffice.

Comment: do you want to know if the point will cross the line before turning around the Earth ? Or where is the point at a given instant (ignoring its movement)

Comment: I want to know where is a point (on the left or right) relative to actually a great circle defined by points A and B. I think you need orientation to understand where is right and where is left. 
@radouxju Does this answer your question?

Comment: Spherical math is more of a math problem than a GIS one. Spheroidal math is usually in the realm of GIS libraries. The US Geodetic Survey has a website with FORTRAN source to solve the partial differential equations for the Forward and Inverse geodetic problems, but defining a local projection and solving in Cartesian space is probably easier.

Comment: @Vince, thanks for your input. Is there any reference I could use as a starting point?